# How do i put a %variable% name in bat / cmd file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

For example if we create a **.bat** file contains:

```
echo "%PATH%"
```

We will get our PATH variable content shown in our command prompt.
So now i want to make a simple script to make this environment variable on my windows and when i execute this script:

```
echo %TESTING%
```

i will see this:

```
%some_other_variable%
```

but, apparently **%some_other_variable%** is executed as if it's a environment variable when we **double click the .bat file**. Is there any way to prevent the execution of looking for variable name in bat/cmd file? currently my script is as follow:

```
setx testing '%development_dir%'
```

and the result i expect is the in my environment variable, i have a key **testing** with value **%development_dir%**, not some real path such as C:\development or anything, still keeping them as %development_dir%.

if it need to change the whole script, it's fine, as long as it's able to be double clicked and make my life easier.

Comment: I'd expect superuser.com to have many answers how to pass string with % to batch file....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double the `%` signs:

```
setx testing "%%development_dir%%"
```

Comment: Yes, but also note that if the value contains `%`, then the `setx` command will create a value of type REG_EXPAND_SZ (Expandable String). Therefore, if development_dir is already defined and you then do `echo %testing%` then it will echo whatever development_dir will expand to.